# How to create a slope

Tags: modeling

Hey so i want to do a straight slope between the cubes, as shown by the black drawing. Any easy way of doing it? My solution of creating another cube cute it in half and try to get it to fit but that cant be the easiest way?

Thanks :)

[image: Picture]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Please give us further information. Are those cubes separate meshes or one mesh? You can also upload your .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then click 'edit' beneath your question, paste the code given to you there and click 'Save Edits'.

Comment: Its a few meshes, i have points in every corner if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tab into edit mode
2. Select and delete these interior faces

[image]

3. Select these verts and hit <kbd>f</kbd> to make them a face

[image]

4. Select these verts and hit <kbd>f</kbd> to make them a face

[image]

5. Select these verts and hit <kbd>f</kbd> to make them a face

[image]